# Eclipse support for Glassfish 5

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, payara, glassfish-5

Does anyone know if there will be support for GlassFish 5 in Eclipse in nearer future (GlassFish Tools supports 3.1 and 4.x)?

Is there another way to integrate Glassfish in Eclipse besides GlassFish Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) now supports Glassfish 5[image][image]

for Eclipse photon users checkout my question and the chosen answer [Cannot install Glassfish tools in Eclipse photon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338220/cannot-install-glassfish-tools-in-eclipse-photon)

Answer (score 12):

GlassFish Tools just checks for a version as follows:

```
Version version = getVersion();

if (!version.matches("[3.1-5)")) {
    return new Status(Status.ERROR, GlassfishToolsPlugin.SYMBOLIC_NAME, Messages.unsupportedVersion);
}
```

Where `getVersion()` is obtained from reading `[install dir]/glassfish/modules/glassfish-api.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and then the `Bundle-Version` entry.

So a hacky way to get Eclipse working with GlassFish 5 and Payara 5 is:

1. cd [install dir]/glassfish/modules/
2. mkdir META-INF
3. unzip -p glassfish-api.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF > META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
4. vim META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
5. Change Bundle-version to start with a `4` and make sure digits are all single (i.e. 181 should become 0 or so)
6. zip -u glassfish-api.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Now you can add a runtime and server for GlassFish 5 and Payara 5 as you would normally do, and start, debug, deploy etc.

For illustration, the entry to be changed looks as follows:

```
Bundle-Name: Public APIs of Glassfish
Bundle-Version: 5.181.0.Alpha4-SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
```

Should become:

```
Bundle-Name: Public APIs of Glassfish
Bundle-Version: 4.0.0.Alpha4-SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
```

The GlassFish tooling is currently in proposal to be donated to Eclipse, so it may take a while to be updated. Meanwhile, I'm planning to create a derivative version before long with some extra enhancements, but that too may take some time.

Comment: Interesting approach - Ill give this a try tonight

Comment: I tried this and it lets you install Glassfish 5 on eclipse. The only problem is that you cant connect up Java 9 JDK. Thanks Arjan because it lets me do work in eclipse using GF5

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no support yet, but you could build your JavaEE app (EAR,WAR) grab the  `.war|ear` file and paste it in

```
[GF_LOCATION]\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\[DOMAIN]\autodeploy\
```

Then go to `[GF_LOCATION]\glassfish5\bin\`

Open a terminal and run:

```
asadmin start-domain [DOMAIN]
```

If you've configured your app correctly, you should be able to access you application locally, something like:

```
localhost:8080/YourApp/
```

If you require a `datasource` and `connection_pool` then from bin, run:

```
asadmin add-resources [location_to_you_app's_glassfish-resources.xml]
```

This should add the configuration needed in GF5 to run your app.

## Alternative

Use Netbeans, I've been able to configure Glassfish 5 in netbeans. Unfortunately, currente version, 8.2 doesn't have JavaEE 8 detection and automatic file completion yet, so you will have to add this configuration manually if you  plan to use `JSF 2.3,Servlet 4.0, etc ...`, but at least you are able con configure and run you applications from your IDE onto Glassfish 5.

Comment: Interesting detail: The Java EE 8 - "First Cup Indroduction" recommends Glassfish5 and NetBeans >= 8.2 or Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) and describes the integration of Glassfish5 in NetBeans: https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/intro002.html

Answer (score -2):

To integrate payara5 with Eclipse 4.7.1a via Oracle "GlassFish Tools" I hat to modify within file \payara5\glassfish\modules\glassfish-api.jar the file META-INF\MANIFEST.MF at the end of the content as follows:

...;version="4.0.0"
Bundle-Name: Public APIs of Glassfish
Bundle-Version: 4.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_152