# Cannot install Glassfish tools in Eclipse Photon / Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-5, eclipse-photon

Eclipse cannot install glassfish tools. under Oracle folder of server there is only options for Webllogic and cloud, The glassfish option appears only ONE time whe I first tried to install it. an after it no longer shows up

[image]

I have tried to remove eclipse an re-extartc it again but the same problem still occurs. What's the problem here? does Anyboy have installed glassfish tools on Phtoton successfully?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Go to `Help > Install New Software...`

Add the [GlassFish Tools](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.glassfish-tools/downloads) Update Site

http://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.0/repository

as repository (or add the URL under `Work with:` directly) and install the tools via the wizard.

Comment: Thanks that worked. However why isn't this already added to eclipse by default?

Comment: I have had a NullPointerException with 2018-12 on click to add new server.

Comment: As of 24/Jul/2022, if anybody wants to install Glassfish tools in Eclipse, use the link http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/ in the "Install new software" form.

Comment: oops , Not Found! now what we can do?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the new eclips. Try eclipse neon instead of your current eclipse and it will work

Answer (score 1):

this will work for Eclips lastest version up to this point:

1-first go to : https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.glassfish-tools/downloads

2-Install Eclipse Sapphire: https://download.eclipse.org/sapphire/9.1.1/repository/

3-then go to : https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/

4-copy URL link above.

5-open your eclips : go to help > install new software

6-paste the link that you copied in "Work with" text field and then press ENTER

7-then click on next and follow installation.( your need to restart your eclips after finishing installation )

8-enjoy buddy.

Comment: oops , Not Found! now what we can do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the sapphire  .zip  plugin and install it to eclipse

http://mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/sapphire/9.1.1/sapphire-repository-9.1.1.zip

2. Download the glassfish .zip plugin and install it in to eclipse

https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/gf-tools-repository-1.0.1.201904090220.zip

3. Download the Glassfish server and add it as a new server to eclipse

http://mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/glassfish/glassfish-5.1.0.zip

Comment: I have seen exactly the same thing answered elsewhere and it was deleted by a moderator. Was that also you? Do you rememeber the reason given for deletion?

Comment: Yes. it was. Reason:: duplicate answer

Comment: oops , Not Found! now what we can do?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with Eclipse 2021-03, but it doesn't work.
It seems to be working with Eclipse 2020-12.
Instructions can be found here (including the right Eclipse version): https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.glassfish-tools/downloads

Hope it can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Help-> Install New Software -> Add..

Add this URL to *Location*, [http://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.0/repository](http://As%20you%20are%20on%20the%20latest,%20you%20might%20try%20http://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.0/repository%20,%20the%20Update%20Site%20for%20the%20tools%20now%20that%20they%20are%20a%20project%20at%20the%20Eclipse%20Foundation.%20Work%20with%20that%20URL%20from%20the%20Help-%3EInstall%20New%20Software%20menu%20in%20Eclipse.) .
Add a Name and proceed

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse GlassFish Tools** is archived. The project become inactive and you can not use for new version of Eclipse IDE. You can you **Payara Tools** instead:

*Payara Server* is an open-source application server derived from *GlassFish Server Open Source Edition*, so you can use it for *Glassfish* as well.

---

Follow These steps:

1. Find *Payara Tools* in *Eclipse Marketplace...*
2. When create new server choose payara and in configuration of **Payara location** add **Glassfish server location** instead:

[image]